# Laravel Eloquent eat memory

Tags: laravel, memory-leaks

why this query is increase my Memory after Each loop?
how can i Free that result?

i need get All result then merge them for process a business logic 
Below is not use for display, so i am not paginate them normally.

```
public function getUser($startId, $endId)
{
    $query = User::where('action', 'register')
        ->whereBetween('id', [$startId, $endId])
        ->whereNotNull('user_id');

    return $query->get(['users.*']);
}
```

User table have about 20k Record and this code below read each 1000 record.

```
$chunk = 1000;

for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i += $chunk) {
    $userLists = $this->getUser($i, $i + $chunk);

    echo memory_get_usage();//It increase
}
```

I was research and put `DB::disableQueryLogs()` but still eat memory

Comment: You cant make pagination? Why are you making chunks manually?

Comment: you are not eager loading at all. You can make use of a lot of helper methods: like ->with() ->limit()  ->take() ->paginate()

Comment: i need get All result then merge them for process a business logic

Comment: Can you show what you need to do with the results as there may be a much easier/more efficient way of doing what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to work with thousands of database records, consider using the chunk method. This method retrieves a small chunk of the results at a time and feeds each chunk into a Closure for processing.

[Chunking query results](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#chunking-results)

```
DB::table('users')
    ->where('action', 'register')
    ->whereBetween('id', [$startId, $endId])
    ->whereNotNull('user_id')
    ->chunk(100, function ($users) {
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        //
    }
});
```